# Internet Explorer asks to download POST request as a download

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have inherited a PHP script that does a lot of logic with in-url POST. Once we make the request within IE9, it asks the user for a download of type "true" with a size that closely resembles the POST request. At no point do we see any behavior where the data isn't being saved on the server -- the expected behavior after submit is to simple ask for a download.

The actual POST call is being fired using jQuery.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "profile/edit-profile-info.php",
  data:"mail="+mail,
  success: function() {
    console.log('Success!!!');
    location.reload('true'); //Reloads the page with the form
  }
}).done(function() {
    console.log('Done!!!');
    location.reload('true'); //Reloads the page with the form
});
```

And the reload command is inherited within the browser object space, from what I can tell.

The actual PHP script that handles this data essentially saves the data in an ORM (not in the code) and returns a request as text/plain

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$data->record->mail = $_POST['mail'];
```

We tried sending another Content Type as a request and it fails to function in Chrome, Firefox, et al.

Looking at the inherited HTML, the fields are populated in a hierarchy without a form tag, which gives me pause as to that being the cause. I'm not entirely sure if that's a culprit. Unfortunately I can't readily give out a demo for review. But if anyone has seen this or has any ideas on the cause, insight would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you probably have an encoding issue  Try `data: {mail: mail},` instead of what you have.  Next, capture the response from your PHP script so we can see the headers and what not.

Comment: I am kicking around the idea of redoing it all as JSON. The response (as seen in the code) is agnostic to whatever request we have in the PHP file, it simply just reloads the page.

Comment: You don't have to use JSON... I'm just saying you have a serialization problem and if you pass in an object, jQuery will do all the escaping in your querystring-format POST data.

Comment: Well, I tried the approach of encapsulation and nothing changed. I grabbed a screen of what the request looks like (sans the POSTDATA which is pretty much the same as above, but with more records) [here](http://imgur.com/ofdAQv5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commas around true in location.reload('true'); it requires a boolean and your inputting it as a string which is not what IE is expecting.